# mysql in NodeJS: Executing second SELECT query on each 'result' of first SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Is this the right practice?

Also I'm interested in final object - bigMap, How do I retrieve it?

```
​var query1 = connection.query('SELECT * FROM posts');
bigMap={}
query1
  .on('result', function(row) {
    processRow(row[pKey], function(map) {
      bigMap=Object.assign(bigMap,map )
    });
  })

processRow(fKey, function(cb) {
  var query2 = connection.query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE field='+fKey+';');
  var map={}
  query2
   .on('result', function(row) {
     map[row[something]]=row[somethingElse]
   })
   .on('end', function(row) {
     cb(map);
   })
});​
```

Comment: This is called N+1 select.  Use join.